# How to concatenate multiple properties of same element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with personal information like names and ages. I want to combine some of those properties to create a new property for each element in the array.

From this array:

```
var list = [{name: "James", lastName: "M.", age: 58}, {name: "Rachel", lastName: "W.", age: 51}];
```

I have created a new entry with:

```
list.forEach(function(itm){
  itm.username = {...list.firstName, ...list.last};
});
```

I want to combine `list.firstName` with `list.lastName` to create `list.username`. `list.username` would consist of a concatenation of `list.firstName` and `list.lastName`.

I have tried using the `.assign()` operator with no success, it just results in `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. I am for some reason getting the same error message when attempting to simply view individual array properties via `console.log(list.firstName[0]);`.

Comment: `list.firstName` or `list.firstName[0]` do not exist, `list[0].firstName` does, but you don't need any of them. `itm.username = itm.firstName + itm.lastName;` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Related: [Concatenate each object property values of javascript array , properties are list of strings in javascript](/q/71812690/4642212), [How to concatenate two string fields into one in a JavaScript array?](/q/34576386/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this is javascript (based on the question's tag). In which case the code you are trying to execute seems wrong.

#### Solution to Question

```
var list = [{firstName: "James", lastName: "M.", age: 58}, {firstName: "Rachel", lastName: "W.", age: 51}];

list.forEach((entry) => {
   entry.fullName = entry.firstName + " " + entry.lastName; 
});

console.log(list[0].fullName);
```

In this solution, I am simply looping through all the elements of the array and assigning a new property "fullName" with the values of the element's own property.

**There are multiple ways to do it, this is just the most simplest way to clear your understanding.**

#### To display the individual property

```
console.log(list[0].firstName);
```

Note, the array index accessor is after the array name `list` and not after the attribute/property name `firstName` in this case.

Also in your provided code there is no attribute `firstName` so do have some checks in place else it will use `undefined` value and might throw some error depending on your development environment.

#### Computed Attribute (getter accessor)

You should also think about how the array data will behave if the value of the attributes/properties changes.

For example if you change the `firstName` attribute/property then you need to remember to update the `fullName` attribute/property as well, else they will be out of sync.

The more efficient way to do this task is to have the attribute/property as a computed attribute/property (think functions or more accurately *getters*)

#### Sample Code

```
var list = [{
  firstName: "James",
  lastName: "M.",
  age: 58,
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  },
}, {
  firstName: "Rachel",
  lastName: "W.",
  age: 51,
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  },
}];


console.log(list[0].fullName);
```

You can learn more about getters as well as setters at [JavaScript Accessors (Getters and Setters)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp)

Comment: Well, there's no property called `list.firstName`. It prints `undefined M.`

Comment: Yes, had mentioned that in my answer, but have now updated it to include the magic of JavaScript Accessors (Getters and Setters), which is far more suited for this type of computed attribute/properties.

Answer (score 0):

**I see two bugs in your code.**

1. The key for first name is 'name' in your list of objects and you've been trying the use 'firstName' while concatenating.
2. You have been trying to merge the properties of objects in the for loop, where you need to merge the values.

**Here's the Solution:**

```
var list = [{firstName: "James", lastName: "M.", age: 58}, {firstName: "Rachel", lastName: "W.", age: 51}];

list.forEach(function(itm){
    itm.username = itm.firstName + " " + itm.lastName; });

console.log(list)
```

Since the objects are in the list, you will need to provide an index to access the object and its values.

**Examples:**

```
console.log(list[0].username)
```

**Or to get the list of usernames only, you can use:**

```
userNames = list.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.username;
});

console.log(userNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no property called `list.firstName`, I think you mean `list.name`.

The solution is to create a new object called `list.username` and combine `list.name` and `list.lastName` and since you are inside `forEach` function, `list` will be called `itm`. So, it will be `itm.name` and `itm.lastName`.

I have also added `+ " " +` to create a space between the first name and the second name.

```js
var list = [{name: "James", lastName: "M.", age: 58}, {name: "Rachel", lastName: "W.", age: 51}];

list.forEach(function(itm) {
    list.username = itm.name + " " + itm.lastName;

    console.log(list.username);

    /**
    James M.
    Rachel W.
    **/
});
```

As well as there's no property called `list.firstName`, you can't access `list.firstName`, try accessing another one as well.

```js
var list = [{name: "James", lastName: "M.", age: 58}, {name: "Rachel", lastName: "W.", age: 51}];
    
console.log(list[0].name); // James
```