# Convert array to another custom array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the array

```
const array1 = [
  { count: "1", category: "A" },
  { count: "2", category: "B" },
];
```

and I need to convert it to

```
const array2 = [
  { name: "1-A" },
  { name: "2-B" },
];
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Create an empty array2, create a loop that goes in array 1, for each object, you get .count and .category, create another object { name: "count-category" }, then use push method on array2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map array and keep certain properties of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966911/how-to-map-array-and-keep-certain-properties-of-objects)

Comment: or [How to concatenate multiple properties of same element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056356/how-to-concatenate-multiple-properties-of-same-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` method. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const array1 = [
  { count: "1", category: "A" },
  { count: "2", category: "B" },
];

const array2 = array1.map(item => ({ name : `${item.count}-${item.category}`}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You loop over and assign new values.

One of many ways:

```js
const array1 = [
    { count: "1", category: "A" },
    { count: "2", category: "B" },
];
const array2 = array1.map(element => {
    return {
        name: `${element.count}-${element.category}`
    }
});
console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Array.map, you can use foreach / push.
You can have more control inside the callback function of forEach.

```
const array1 = [
  { count: "1", category: "A" },
  { count: "2", category: "B" },
];
let array2  =[]
array1.forEach( (data) => 
{
    array2.push({name : `${data.count}-${data.category}`})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = [
  { count: "1", category: "A" },
  { count: "2", category: "B" },
];
var array2 = [],
  newVar;
for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; index++) {
  newVar = array1[index].count + "-" + array1[index].category;
  array2.push({ name: newVar });
}
```